# Group of two radio buttons is not working using html helper

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I am using two radio buttons in my HTML form in an ASP.NET MVC project.

This is my model.

```
[Display(Name = "Gender")]
public string gender { get; set; }
```

And in view I am declaring two radio buttons using html helper.

```
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(a => a.gender)</label>
<div class="col-sm-9 row">
    <div class="radio-btn pull-left mRight-20">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "male")
        @Html.LabelFor(a => a.gender, "Male")
    </div>
    <div class="radio-btn pull-left">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "female")
        @Html.LabelFor(a => a.gender, "Female")
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is I can click only one button i.e radio button for male. And when I click on female radio button, that time also male is being clicked. Female radio button is not clickable. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `for` attribute of `label` control. You can use the below code to resolve this problem:

```
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(a => a.gender)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9 row">
            <div class="radio-btn pull-left mRight-20">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "male", new { @id="genderMale"})
                <label for="genderMale">Male</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio-btn pull-left">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "female", new { @id = "genderFemale" })
                <label for="genderFemale">Female</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also the radio button is not checked because it is bound to Model. So if you assign gender value in model like  `Model.gender = "male";` then it will set the value of relevant radio button.

Comment: Thanks @Manprit Singh Sahota, it resolved my problem.